# How to make NCR rangers stop attacking me in Fallout New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I am at the beginning of Fallout: New Vegas and am being attacked for apparently no reason by NCR rangers. I'm wearing a Leather Armor (not linked to any faction) so I don't understand how to make them stop (except for killing them, of course...).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your pipboy to see how bad your relationship is with the NCR.  If it is very bad, you may have to load to a much earlier point.  If it is not so bad however, you can try to resolve the situation by gaining a bit of positive fame.  The quest from ranger Andy is very simple, involves killing a couple of legion guys, and gives a bit of fame.

Answer (score 3):

Find out your relationship with the NCR, as a poor reputation can cause them to attack you.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys.
I finally figured out that the NCR kept attacking me because of a bug related to wearing faction armor.

Look [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Fallout:_New_Vegas_factions) for more info about that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i ran into this solution, in a few ways, some seem to have stumbled across it and came to a wrong conclusion, but what actually happens is this:

When equiping a faction specific armor if you do not remove it first(clicking on it) BEFORE storing it or putting on ANY other armor you can glitch the "faction assosication" even while not wearing it. so if you for instance wear Legion armor, then click on the spacesuit armor you can get "stuck" on wearing legion armor while not wearing it.

Solution: Equip the faction armor again and unequip it. If you do not know which faction armor you did this "bug" with, then equip all faction specific armors and unequip them one at a time(khan,legion,ncr, etc) Only one piece of each is needed to turn the setting to 0.

Secondary bug: This also can really screw up your faction standings when killing other things(several times Legion has been neutral to me, despite me killing them every chance i got).